# Get specific file with name containing specific string from directory using FTP

Tags: windows, batch-file, download, ftp

I have made below batch file to get some files using `ftp` from server...
Now I need to get specific  file from the directory below using `mget`.
Not all file in that directory. And I need to pass it as variable not static.

> mget /home/backup/dump/*.*

**example**

the directory `dump` has files

```
a_0509_kasjada.dump
a_0009_kaoi.dump
a_0033_msdhaa.dump
a_0579_qptcla.dump
```

I want to `mget` only the file name that contains `0009` pass it as variable.

```
@ECHO OFF
TITLE %1 - Get Dumps backup

SET @FileDate=%DATE:~10,4%%DATE:~4,2%%DATE:~7,2%%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%


:PING 
ping    %2   -n 1
IF %errorlevel% NEQ 0 goto :PING


REM --- Check directories existence
IF NOT EXIST "D:\Backup" MKDIR "D:\Backup" 
IF NOT EXIST "D:\Backup\%1\" MKDIR "D:\Backup\%1" 
IF NOT EXIST "D:\Backup\%1\%@FileDate%\" MKDIR "D:\Backup\%1\%@FileDate%"

ECHO open %2> %1_tmp.srjd
ECHO oracle>> %1_tmp.srjd
ECHO olAdmin>> %1_tmp.srjd
ECHO lcd "D:\Backup\%1\%@FileDate%">> %1_tmp.srjd
ECHO bin>> %1_tmp.srjd

ECHO mget /home/backup/dump/*.*>> %1_tmp.srjd

ECHO bye>> %1_tmp.srjd

REM --- Launch FTP and pass it the script
FTP -i -s:%1_tmp.srjd

REM --- Cleanup.
DEL %1_tmp.srjd

REM --- PAUSE
EXIT
```

Answer (score 0):

So just use your variable in the `mget` command:

```
set VAR=0009

ECHO get /home/backup/dump/*%VAR%* >> %1_tmp.srjd
```